# how to print duplicate character from string in java

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.*;
public class DuplicateCharacters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter String: ");
        String str = s.nextLine();

        for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<str.length();j++)

            {
            if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j))
            {

                System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
            }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> My code works for string contains 2 duplicate character only ..

e.g.  suppose input= india it prints i 
    but when input aaa , output = a a a..it should print a once only

Comment: I have it using set.. i need it using string only so

Answer (score 2):

Attempt to put every newly read character into a `Set<Character>`. If adding to the set returns false, then add it to a set tracking all repeat characters. Here's pseudocode for it:

```
Set<Character> uniqueChars = new HashSet<Character>();
Set<Character> repeats = new HashSet<Character>();
for(int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (!uniqueChars.add(str.charAt(i)) {
        repeats.add(str.charAt(i));
    }
}

// now loop through the repeats set and print out each one.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;

public class DuplicateCharacters {

    static final int NO_OF_CHARS = 256;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter String: ");
       String str = s.nextLine();
       int count[] = new int[NO_OF_CHARS];

       for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
       {
          count[str.charAt(i)]++;
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_CHARS; i++) 
          if(count[i] > 1) 
             System.out.printf("%c", i);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a third-party library, the following will work using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
String str = "india";
MutableCharSet dupes = Strings.asChars(str).toBag().selectDuplicates().toSet();
System.out.println(dupes.makeString(""));  // outputs i
```

The `Strings` class, will return a `CharAdapter` from the call to `asChars`. The `toBag` method will return a `MutableCharBag`, which has all the `char` values in the `String` with their corresponding counts. The `selectDuplicates` method will return another `MutableCharBag` with only the `char` values that have more than one occurrence. The `toSet` method returns a `MutableCharSet`, which will have the unique `char` values that had duplicates. The `makeString("")` method will return a String of the chars stored in the `MutableCharSet` with no separator between them.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by decomposing the problem into two parts. First, you need a method to count the number of occurrences of a given character from a given start index. That might look something like,

```
static int countFrom(String str, char ch, int start) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ch) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then you can use that with a `Set<Character>` (to track which characters you have already used) like

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter String: ");
String str = s.nextLine();
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    if (!set.contains(ch)) {
        int count = countFrom(str, ch, i);
        if (count > 1) {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
        set.add(ch);
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

and without a `Set`, you can emulate one with a `String` like

```
String setString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    if (!setString.contains(String.valueOf(ch))) {
        int count = countFrom(str, ch, i);
        if (count > 1) {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
        setString += ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: @shraddha if it works for you mark as accepted answer so question be removed from unanswer question list :)

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to solve it..

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter String: ");
    String str = s.nextLine();

    String duplicates = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length(); j++)

        {
            if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {

                if (!duplicates.contains(String.valueOf(str.charAt(j)))) {
                    duplicates += str.charAt(j);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert String in char array and append it to String builder and check if String builder Already contains that char then print that duplicate char.

```
public static void findduplicate(String word) {

        char arr[] = word.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : arr) {
            int index = s.indexOf("" + c);
            if (index != -1) {
                System.out.println("duplicate character "+c);
            } else {
                s.append(c);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Adding explanation to your answer will help users

Answer (score 0):

Or consider a Map

```
    String word = "aiaiiab";
    Map <Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer> ();
    for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
        Integer count = charMap.get(new Character(c));
        if (count == null) {
            charMap.put(new Character(c), 1);
        }
        else {
            charMap.put(new Character(c), count.intValue() + 1);
        }
    }

    for (Entry<Character, Integer> obj : charMap.entrySet()) {

        if (obj.getValue() > 1) {
            System.out.println(obj.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.java2novice.algos;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class DuplicateCharsInString {

public void findDuplicateChars(String str){

    Map<Character, Integer> dupMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    char[] chrs = str.toCharArray();
    for(Character ch:chrs){
        if(dupMap.containsKey(ch)){
            dupMap.put(ch, dupMap.get(ch)+1);
        } else {
            dupMap.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }
    Set<Character> keys = dupMap.keySet();
    for(Character ch:keys){
        if(dupMap.get(ch) > 1){
            System.out.println(ch+"--->"+dupMap.get(ch));
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String a[]){
    DuplicateCharsInString dcs = new DuplicateCharsInString();
    dcs.findDuplicateChars("Java2Novice");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GFG  
{ 
  static final int NO_OF_CHARS = 256; 

  /* Fills count array with frequency of characters */
  static void fillCharCounts(String str, int[] count) 
  { 
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length();  i++) 
      count[str.charAt(i)]++; 
  } 

  /* Print duplicates present in the passed string */
  static void printDups(String str) 
  { 
    // Create an array of size 256 and fill count of every character in it 
    int count[] = new int[NO_OF_CHARS]; 
    fillCharCounts(str, count); 

    for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_CHARS; i++) 
      if(count[i] > 1) 
        System.out.printf("%c,  count = %d \n", i,  count[i]); 
  } 

  // Driver Method 
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    String str = "test string"; 
    printDups(str); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. It's better if you can add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are not that much of a help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String abc = "22533"; // Initialize String variable
    int cnt = 0; // declaring integer variable with value as 0
    char[] inp = str.toCharArray(); // converts the given string into a sequence of characters

    System.out.println("Duplicate Characters are:");
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { // This loop starts with first character of the given String
        for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length(); j++) { // This loop starts with second character of the given string
            if (inp[i] == inp[j]) { // Comparing first loop index value with second loop index value of inp character array.
                System.out.println(inp[j]); // If value matches, it will print result.
            }
        }
    }
```